# gorm save method causing a select query to fire

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using grails 1.3.7 and zkoss and my domain model is as below, I load the Person entity in session 1 and make changes to it through the UI.

The on press of save in session 2 I want to save the entity.

So from my composer/controller I call a service method(transactional) and then do person.save(), When i see the sql queries being fired I see a query which tries to retrieve the employee object.

After which the save is fired and throws a nonuniqueobjectexception
Exception

> > org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.nthdimenzion.domain.Employee#2]

Query

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id7_0_, this_.version as version7_0_, this_.emp_id as emp4_7_0_, this_.person_id as person5_7_0_ from person_role this_ where this_.class='com.nthdimenzion.domain.Employee' and this_.emp_id=?

class PersonService {
static transactional = true
def savePerson(Person person) {
    person = person.save();
}
```

}

```
class Person extends Party{

String firstName;
String middleName;  
static hasMany = [ personRoles : PersonRole ] -- lazy loaded
```

....
}

```
class PersonRole {
public static enum ROLETYPES{
    EMPLOYEE,AUTHOR
};
public boolean hasRoleType (ROLETYPES roleType){
    return false;
}
static transients = ['ROLETYPES']
static constraints = {
}
 }



class Employee extends PersonRole{
def empRoleType = [ROLETYPES.EMPLOYEE]
String empId
    static belongsTo = [person:Person]
 static transients = ['empRoleType', 'uid']
static constraints = {
    books(nullable:true)
    empId(unique:true)
}
static hasMany = [books:Book]
static mapping = { books cascade:"all" }
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
  ......
}
```

Is this behavior correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have specified in `Employee` mapping that `empId` is the primary key - that's probably the only reason for `NonUniqueObjectException`.

The SQL query must come from an unique constraint on `empId` field.

Why not using Grails'/Hibernate implicit `id`, are you using a legacy database with a specific mapping?

**edit** I don't see why would unique constraint cause `NonUniqueObjectException` -  can you please try it without the constraint?

If the problem remains, you must have saved the object twice from the same session - no idea how it can happen, maybe by `merge()`-ing an `Employee` from earlier session.

The SQL query is caused by uniqueness constraint and it's the right thing.

Comment: No i have not I did double check this ! My employee create table is as belowCREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`emp_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

Comment: Does `Employee` class have a `static mapping` field or `static constraints`? Or do you use Hibernate annotations or XML config?

Comment: it has both static mapping and static constraints,updated my question to show the static mappings and constraints

Comment: I am pretty surprised, If i remove the uniqueness constraint it works perfectly !! why does the uniqueness constraint cause the select queries to fire ?

Comment: just because it needs to be checked. Before issuing `INSERT`, you need to check if you're violating any constraints. I wonder why wouldn't Hibernate process `SqlException`/`NonUniqueObjectException` instead, if database unique constraint is there - but it's the way it works.

Comment: However this is going to cause a NonUniqueObjectException each time , you use a entity with a unique constraint , in a one-to-many relationship with cascading save or updates ? I think something is going wrong here ? ...

Comment: Not sure. Can it be your logic that causes uniqueness violation? Did there ever appear 2 records with same `emp_id` in database after you dropped the constraint?

Comment: Not sure if i got your question completely,'Can it be your logic that causes uniqueness violation' , my understanding was that because i put a unique constraint on my entity hibernate does a select to check if the currently persisting entity will cause a unique constraint violation ... Yes after i remove the constraint , I can put in multiple records with same emp_id

Comment: I mean - if several records with same `empId` appeared without direct user command, then it's the application code logic that caused the record to duplicate. In that case, no need to look for `NonUniqueObjectException` cause in Grails or wherever outside.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why hibernate fired that Select this_.id as id7_0_, this_.version as version7_0_, this_.emp_id as emp4_7_0_, this_.person_id as person5_7_0_ from person_role this_ where this_.class='com.nthdimenzion.domain.Employee' and this_.emp_id=?
when i had the unique constraint , I do not understand what the it does with the resultset of this query and how it uses it to verify that the object being persisted currently will not throw a unique constraint. I have spawned a seprate question this on topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537806/grails-unique-constraint)