# Grails Controller "show" action causing 2 select queries with a "unique" constraint

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

On grails 2.4.4 using H2 and PostgreSQL for development, I see this odd behavior when the "show" action of a scaffolded controller is called on a domain object, which has a "unique" constraint on its "name" property: there are 2 SQL select queries executed.

First query loads the object by the object's ID, and the followup query loads the object by its "name".

While this makes sense when an object is being saved (to check for uniqueness before saving, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987968/gorm-save-method-causing-a-select-query-to-fire)) I see no sense in the 2 queries in case of a "show" action. When the unique constraint is removed, only one query is executed. Is this the expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Example object:

```
class Book {
    String name
    String author

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
    }
}
```

The controller is scaffolded, so generally, the show action looks like this:

```
def show(Book bookInstance) {
    respond bookInstance
}
```

The 2 logged SQL queries (shortened) look like this:

```
select ... from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
select ... from book this_ where this_.name=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bookInstance` parameter of the *show* action is treated as a [Command object](http://www.grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#7.1.10%20Command%20Objects) here, which means it is being validated before it is passed to the action. Domain class constraints are therefore checked and the declared uniqueness of the `name` field is verified by the second query.

The check is really useless here, but the mechanism is intended for binding request parameters (other than `id`) to the domain class properties, where the validation makes sense.

To prevent the validation, instantiate the *Book* object like this:

```
def show() {
    Book bookInstance = Book.get(params.id)
        respond bookInstance
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and especially for the background information on Command Objects, appreciated!